# Autobox TypeDefs in Objective-C (LLVM 4+)

Tags: objective-c, autoboxing

I have this type of Enum with TypeDef:

```
typedef enum {
    ControlDisplayOptionNone = 0,
    ControlDisplayOptionOne = 100
} ControlDisplayOption;
```

And I'd like to be able to put them in an array like this:

```
- (NSArray *)displayOptions {
    return @[@ControlDisplayOptionNone];
}
```

but that won't work, and even this won't work:

```
NSNumber *test = @ControlDisplayOptionNone;
```

the only option that will work is traditional:

```
return @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:ControlDisplayOptionNone]];
```

Is there any way to use autoboxing for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use parentheses: `@(ControlDisplayOptionNone)`

The syntax is explained in the [Clang documentation for Objective-C Literals](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html). The "Boxed Enums" section says:

> Cocoa frameworks frequently define constant values using *enums*. Although enum values are integral, they may not be used directly as boxed literals (this avoids conflicts with future `'@'`-prefixed Objective-C keywords). Instead, an enum value must be placed inside a boxed expression.

Comment: Why I have to come back in 5 minutes to accept this answer I don't know. But while we're here, is there a place that you know this from (citation)? THANKS this works.

Comment: @Yar Citation added! So there you go, you need parens in case there is someday an Objective-C keyword `@ControlDisplayOptionNone` :-)